# Вывод данных из таблицы SQLite в Android

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

Начал разбираться с SQLite в Android. Понял как узнать количество данных в курсоре, но не понял как вывести эти данные:

```
  userCursor = db.rawQuery("select " + COLUMN_NAME + " from " + TABLE, null);//Получаем все данные из таблицы TABLE(users)
            textBD.setText(Integer.toString(userCursor.getCount()));// В getCount получили сколько записей содержит курсор
            userCursor.moveToFirst();//Перевели курсор к первому значению
```

Полный код:

```
@Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            userCursor = db.rawQuery("select " + COLUMN_NAME + " from " + TABLE, null);//Получаем все данные из таблицы TABLE(users)
            textBD.setText(Integer.toString(userCursor.getCount()));// В getCount получили сколько записей содержит курсор
            userCursor.moveToFirst();//Перевели курсор к первому значению
            if (userCursor.moveToFirst()) {
                while (!userCursor.isAfterLast()) {
                    String data = userCursor.getString(userCursor.getColumnIndex("data"));

                    // обрабатываем data

                    // двигаемся к следующему значению
                    userCursor.moveToNext();
                }
            }
// не забывайте закрыть курсор
            userCursor.close();
            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "ОКЕЙ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            toast.show();
        }
    });
}
```

Ошибки:

```
Process: com.example.mysql_legkosuka, PID: 10864
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Couldn't read row 0, col -1 from CursorWindow.  Make sure the Cursor is initialized correctly before accessing data from it.
         at android.database.CursorWindow.nativeGetString(Native Method)
         at android.database.CursorWindow.getString(CursorWindow.java:438)
         at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.getString(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:51)
         at com.example.mysql_legkosuka.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:51)
         at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4756)
         at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19749)
         at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Чтобы получить данные из курсора нужно пройтись циклом по нему:

```
if (userCursor.moveToFirst()) {
    while (!userCursor.isAfterLast()) {
        String data = userCursor.getString(userCursor.getColumnIndex("data"));

        // обрабатываем data

        // двигаемся к следующему значению
        userCursor.moveToNext();
    }
}

// не забывайте закрыть курсор
userCursor.close();
```

Comment: В правках добавил полный код, и ошибки.

Comment: Я дал пример кода, а не решение вашей задачи, этим должны заниматься только вы. Пожалуйста, для начала прочитайте документацию по работе с SQLite в Android и изучите лучше программирование на Java.

Comment: @Romag можно увидеть что здесь нет проверки на то что есть ли данные в вашей таблице (запросе) вам нужно самому посмотреть есть ли там данные и не считывать из пустого)

Answer (score 1):

Если используете список, тогда можно использовать SimpleCursorAdapter - ну наверное это для простого примера

```
scAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.item, cursor, from, to);
    lvData = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvData);
    lvData.setAdapter(scAdapter);
```

Если же хотите делать что-то особенное, тогда  в Вашем распоряжении есть `RecyclerView` + `Cursor`, но тогда придется следить за изменениями и т.д. (не самая простая задача).